# In YUI3, is there a way to "reset" models to the previous saved values?

Tags: javascript, yui, yui3

I'm using models in yui3, and although there are functions like reset() and undo(), they don't quite accomplish what I'm looking for.

I set values at different times, but may want to just undo everything to the point of the last save... is there a way to do so at this time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 3.5.0pr2 (pr2 is currently on the Yahoo! CDN; 3.5.0 GA will be released in mid-March), you can try something like this:

```
var MyModelClass = Y.Base.create('mine', Y.Model, [], {
    initializer: function () {
        this._saveState();
        this.after('save', this._saveState);
    },
    _saveState: function (e) {
        this._lastState = this.toJSON();
    },
    restoreLastSaved: function () {
        this.setAttrs(this._lastState);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks! I'd upvote the answer but I don't have the rep to do it yet :(